# prototype does not match function definition, but it does

Tags: c, types, declaration

I have a program with 2 functions, one of them counts number of words in a file, and works perfectly, and the other one counts the number of tymes a specific word appears in file. This las function does work perfectly (i have tested it isolated from the main), but when i ordered everything in the main, with a functions.h file, i get this.

The function with the problem is word_cnt(FILE*, char*)

when i compile, i get this:

`word.c:3:5: error: conflicting types for ‘word_cnt’`
 
`int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char* argv[2])`

```
In file included from word.c:1:
functions.h:7:5: note: previous declaration of ‘word_cnt’ was here
int word_cnt(FILE*, char*);
```

in the word.c file, (file which contains the word_cnt function with the problem) the function is defined like this

```
int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char* argv[2])
```

and in the header file, the prototype is like this:

```
int word_cnt(FILE*, char*);
```

I do not understand....the definition is correct, why does the compiler think i am redefyning it?

IMAGE HERE
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zhS3iaFURJ0HyRgcy733NsT4trfzFDve

Comment: Why do you believe the definition to be correct in the face of evidence to the contrary?

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of trouble by simply copying the function definition from the .c file, paste it into the .h file, and put a semicolon at the end. Then you don't need to waste time thinking about such things. In other words, the prototype in the .h file should be `int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char* argv[2]);`

Answer (score 4):

In the source file, the second argument has type "array 2 of pointer to char".

In the header, the second argument has type "pointer to char".

These are not the same types, and are not compatible. The former is effectively a `char **`, while the latter is a `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters having array types are implicitly adjusted by the compiler to pointers to element types of the arrays.

So, for example these function declarations

```
int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char* argv[2]);
int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char* argv[10]);
int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char* argv[100]);
int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char* argv[]);
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function that by the compiler are adjusted to

```
int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char** argv);
```

So it is evident that these two function declarations

```
int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char** argv);
```

and

```
int word_cnt(FILE* fp, char* argv);
```

are different.